# Aws ip range ssh restrictions

Tags: cloud

I'm studying for my aws cert and I'm trying understand the below section of the documentation on EC2 instances:

In the Source field, choose My IPto automatically populate the field with the public IPv4 address of your local computer. Alternatively, choose Custom and specify the public IPv4 address of your computer or network in CIDR notation. For example, if your IPv4 address is 203.0.113.25, specify 203.0.113.25/32 to list this single IPv4 address in CIDR notation. If your company allocates addresses from a range, specify the entire range, such as203.0.113.0/24.

What I want to do is restrict access to my EC2 instance to the people on my home network so let's just say that's 192.168.X.X. How would I go about doing that? The documentation is not clear enough to me. Thanks. Maybe a couple of different examples would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can only restrict access to your local network's public IP. Local addresses such as 192.168.x.x don't route over the internet so your EC2 instance will never see them. On a home network you usually only have one public IP which is outside IP of your router.

I should add that in your router, you should see your public IP and subnet mask. There are plenty of places on line to convert an IP/subnet combo to CIDR notation if you don't know how to do it manually.

Comment: When I said 192.168.X.X I was only using that as an example. You could put any up there. I just want to be able to ssh into the EC2 instance from my home network after getting a new ip after shutting off my computer for the day.

Comment: Well, the example you used just happened to be one that you can't use for that purpose. LOL

So find the public IP range for your area and then allow the CIDR block for that.

Comment: @user3756741 - The best for you would be to assign an elastic IP address to your ec2 instance. After restart, you can reassign same EIP back to your ec2 instance. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html